# Getting error while create Dynamic CRM Onpremises Linked service in Azure data Factory using IFD authentication

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a Dynamics 365(On premises) linked services in Azure data factory. I have entered following information.

1. Deployment Type : OnPremisesWithIfd
2. Organization Name : Enter valid name
3. Host : Enter valid host
4. Port : 443 (by default)
5. Authentication type : IFD
6. Enter valid username and password

But, I am getting following error:

> Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM: Unable to login to Dynamics CRM, Error was : Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://https//crm-edu.abc.com/CRMDEV:443/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9'

Answer (score 0):

> https://https//crm-edu.abc.com/CRMDEV:443/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9

There is doubled https and also port in wrong part of url. Try entering just yours host part: crm-edu.abc.com into host input field.

Example of configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#dynamics-365-and-dynamics-crm-on-premises-with-ifd